# Can i transfer ETH from coinbase to my etherhwallet?

Tags: cpp-ethereum, myetherwallet, coinbase

I have ETH in my coinbase acct, can I transfer them to my etherwallet acct? How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can transfer funds from any wallet to exchange and vice-versa.

For transferring funds from Coinbase follow the very simple steps.

- Login to your coinbase account
- Go to accounts tab
- Corresponding to your ethereum address you can see 2 buttons send and receive.
- Click on send, On the send dialog, select Wallet Address.
- Enter the amount of digital currency you'd like to send in the Amount field
- Click Continue
- Confirm the details of the transaction and complete the send

For full instructions see [How do I send digital currency? from coinbase](https://support.coinbase.com/customer/en/portal/articles/971437-how-do-i-send-digital-currency-)